# Inserting query to Database is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have written this below code to insert query into my database. I have placed this PHP code on the same page as well as on port.php. It is not working either. Any ideas or suggestions are really appreciated.

Here is my PHP query to insert data to the database

Php code:

```
<?php
//connect to DB
 print_r($_POST); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); //<- here you can switch on and off the error reporting 0 / 1 - makes life easy ;) 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$debug=1;
            $host = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = "mysqlr00tpa55";
     try {
          $myconnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
          // set the PDO error mode to exception    
          $myconnection ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
     $vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
     $nachname = $_POST['nacname'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
     $created = $_POST['created']; //geburtstag
     $plz = $_POST['plz'];
     $ort = $_POST['ort'];
     $strasse = $_POST['strasse'];
     $hnr = $_POST['hnr'];
     $adrZus = $_POST['adrZus'];

     $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `Port_Owner`(`vorname`, `nachname`, `email`, `telefon`, `created`, `plz`, `ort`, `strasse`, `hnr`, `adrZus`)
     VALUES (:vorname,:nachname,:email,:telefon,:created,:plz,:ort,:strasse,:hnr,:adrZus)";

     $pdoResult = $myconnection ->prepare($pdoQuery);

     $pdoExec =  $pdoResult->execute(array(
          ":vorname"=>$vorname,
                                           ":nachname"=>$nachname,
                                           ":email"=>$email,
                                           ":telefon"=>$telefon,
                                           ":created"=>$created,
                                           ":plz"=>$plz,
                                           ":ort"=>$ort,
                                           ":strasse"=>$strasse,
                                           ":hnr"=>$hnr, 
                                           ":adrZus"=>$adrZus));
     if($pdoExec)
     {
        echo 'Attempt to port a new user is successful!';
     }else{
        echo 'Attempt to port a new user is unsuccessful!';
     }
     }
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="port.php" method="post">

<br><br>
    <!--Beginn des Anrede-->
<div class="form1"><br><br>
<div class="names">
    <div class="anrede">
    <label for="Anrede">Anrede
        <select id=" select" name="anrede" >
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="herr">Herr</option>
        <option value="frau">Frau</option>
        <option value="andere">Andere</option>
        </select>
    </label></div>
    <br><br>
<div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">Vorname</label>
    <div><input id="vorname" name="vorname" type="text" class="field text fn" value="<?php echo $value['vorname']; ?>" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Ihr Vorname"></div>
</div>
<div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">Nachname</label>
    <div><input id="nachname" name="nachname" type="text" class="field text fn" value="<?php echo $value['nachname']; ?>" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Ihr Nachname"></div>
</div>
<div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">E-mail-Addresse</label>
    <div><input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="field text fn" value="<?php echo $value['email']; ?>" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Emailadresse"></div>
</div>
<div><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">Telefonnummer</label>
    <div><input id="telefon" name="telefon" type="number" class="field text fn" value="<?php echo $value['telefon']; ?>" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Telefonnummer"></div>
</div>
<div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">Geburtstag</label>
    <div><input id="geburtstag" name="geburtstag" type="date" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $value['created']; ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="3"></div>
</div>
<div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">Plz</label>
    <div><input id="plz" name="plz" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $value['plz']; ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Ihre Postleitzahl"></div><br><br>
   <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">Ort</label>
    <div><input id="ort" name="ort" type="text" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $value['ort']; ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Dein Platz"></div><br><br>
  </div>

<div>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">Stra&beta;e</label>
    <div><input id="strasse" name="strasse" type="text" class="field text fn" value="<?php echo $value['strasse']; ?>" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Deine Stra&beta;e"></div>
</div>

 <div><br><br>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">Hausnummer</label>
    <div><input id="hnr" name="hnr" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $value['hnr']; ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Ihre Hausnummer"></div></div><br><br>
     <div>
      <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">Hausnummerzusatz</label>
      <div><input id="adrZus" name="adrZus" type="number" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $value['adrZus']; ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" placeholder="Zus&#228;tzliche Adresse"></div></div>
<div class="sub"><br>
    <br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suche">
     <input type="submit" name="insert" value="New port">
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

when I insert vorname, nachname and other fields, it says "This page isn't working". Somone help me in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got PDO to throw exceptions on errors? Are any errors showing?

Comment: *"This page isn't working"* Feels like a PHP parse error somewhere else in the code, check the PHP errorlog..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name=` attribute in your form does not match what you're trying to get from the `$_POST` array. For example:

```
<input id="vorname" name="vorname" type="text" class="field text fn" value="<?php echo $value['vorname']; ?>" size="8" tabindex="1" placeholder="Ihr Vorname">
```

`name="vorname"` does not match:

```
$vorname = $_POST['portO_firstN'];
```

Where the identifier should be the same as the name given to the input. Instead, it should be:

```
$vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
```

To match the name given to the input. ALL of your variables in the `$_POST` array are undefined. To see this error add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: That is how you set up your database, you *require* a last name. If you don't want that you have to reconfigure your database table.

Comment: Did you change all of your `$_POST` array variables? `$nachname = $_POST['portO_lastN'];` should be `$nachname = $_POST['nachname'];`

Comment: At the top of your script place a `print_r($_POST);` and add that to your question.

Comment: You have a spelling error `$nachname = $_POST['nacname'];` should be `$nachname = $_POST['nachname'];`

Comment: You would think I have given you enough to be able to troubleshoot this yourself. `$created = $_POST['created'];` is supposed to be for this field `<input id="geburtstag" name="geburtstag" type="date" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $value['created']; ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="3">` The name of that field is `geburtstag` so you should use `$created = $_POST['geburtstag'];`